# How to set the first column value of a GROUPING SETS

Tags: sql

I have the following request :

```
SELECT column1, column2, SUM(column3) as total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((column1, column2), ())
```

Which returns :

| Name1 | Name2 | QTT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | CD | 15 |
| ZE | EF | 15 |
| None | None | 30 |

So `|None|None|30` is the output from the `GROUPING BY SETS`

But I am wondering how to define the first None to be something else :

```
|SubTotal|None|30
```

For example.

The final output would be :

| Name1 | Name2 | QTT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | CD | 15 |
| ZE | EF | 15 |
| SubTotal | None | 30 |

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialect is not provided, but the corresponding part to `GROUPING SETS` is [GROUPING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/grouping_id.html) function:

> Describes which of a list of expressions are grouped in a row produced by a GROUP BY query.
>
> `GROUPING_ID` is not an aggregate function, but rather a utility function that can be used alongside aggregation, **to determine the level of aggregation a row was generated for**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(Name1 TEXT, Name2 TEXT,  QTT INT)
AS    SELECT 'AB','CD',15
UNION SELECT 'ZE','EF',15;

SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(Name1,Name2)=3THEN 'Subtotal' ELSE Name1 END AS Name1
     ,Name2, SUM(QTT) as total
FROM my_table
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((Name1, Name2), ());
```

Output:

[image]

---

Related:

- [SQL Server GROUPING_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Postgresql GROUPING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-GROUPING-TABLE)
- [MySQL GROUPING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_grouping)